# PHPUnit and Webdriver(Selenium2) - Can not pass a string parameter to waitUntil() method

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phpunit

**Environment:**
- Selenium 2.39 Standalone Server
- PHP 5.4.11
- PHPUnit 3.7.28
- Chrome V31 & ChromeDriver v2.7

I want to encapsulate a method for finding elements with `waitUntil()` method, after reading samples [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/ac95df2e718998f4ac91e7000e4d5eb48496c99d/Tests/Selenium2TestCase/WaitUntilTest.php). I tried several times as following:

**Code1:**

```
public function findElement($elementCssPath){
$this->waitUntil(function($testCase) {
try {
$testCase->byCssSelector($elementCssPath);
} catch (PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException $e) {
return TRUE;
}
}, 8000);
}
```

**Code2:**

```
public function findElement($elementCssPath){
$this->waitUntil(function () {
if ($this->byCssSelector($elementCssPath)) {
return true;
}
return null;
}, 20000);
}
```

**Code3:**

```
public function findElement($elementCssPath){
$this->waitUntil(function($elementCssPath) {
try {
$this->byCssSelector($elementCssPath);
} catch (PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException $e) {
return TRUE;
}
}, 8000);
}
```

But all of them reported an error:

```
Undefined variable: elementCssPath
```

I searched a lot on internet ,but there's no further information.
Please help ,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me finally.

```
public function findElementWaitUntil($elementCssPath){
    $this->waitUntil(function() use($elementCssPath){
        if ($this->byCssSelector($elementCssPath)) {
                return true;
            }
                return null;
            }, 10000);
    try{
        $object=$this->byCssSelector($elementCssPath);
        return $object;
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        throw $e;
    }   
}
```

Comment: When the element does not show up before the timeout, a memory leak occurs.